# Exclude the "." from a file extension in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do I the dot when getting the file extension name in rails?

Right now I'm using `File.extname` but it's keeping the "." before giving me the name

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Would this work for you?

```
File.extname('something.jpg').delete('.') #=> 'jpg'
```

You could even wrap it up in a helper:

```
def file_extension(filename)
  File.extname(filename).delete('.')
end

file_extension('something.jpg') #=> 'jpg'
```

Comment: Ruby 1.8, Rails 2.3: `'my.image.ext.jpg'.delete('.') #=> "myimageextjpg"`

Comment: @MrYoshiji That is why I used `File.extname`. Passing 'my.image.ext.jpg' into the method will still result in 'jpg'.

Comment: This isn't as good When trying to deal with files with double-barrelled extensions like `.tar.gz` and `.svg.gz`, since `File.extname` would just return `.gz`.